# ASP.NET MVC with Custom/legacy template management system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates

We have a legacy template management system, which basically returns html files from the disk based upon supplied input values.

For example: TStoreMgr.GetTemplate(contextName, loc, "header.template")

We want to move to ASP.NET MVC, but stay with existing template management system. Is it something possible? If so, is it worth using MVC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with template, usually templates are filled out before being returned to the client.

But from the information you give, yes sure and it's **very easy**, at least if TStoreMgr returns a string and contextName and loc are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply implememnt a view engine and plug it into MVC. This way you can also mix and match between your legacy template and the standard asp.net mvc template engine.

Check out these two tutorials on how to implement your own view engine.

http://www.coderjournal.com/2009/05/creating-your-first-mvc-viewengine/

http://www.comteken.com/web-programming/creating-a-custom-view-engine-in-asp-net-mvc-2/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is all about view/presentation related thing. You can write "GetTemplate(contextName, loc, "header.template")" as a Custom Helper Method and it will do the thing for you.